# Understanding Local Scope

Tags: javascript

I can't manage to change the value of 'i' no matter how hard I try...

**My code is the following:**

```
function changeValue(){
    //neither 'var i=99;' or 'i=99;' interferes with the 'i' on myFunction
}

function myFunction(){
    var i;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        alert(i);
        changeValue();
        alert(i);
    }
}

myFunction();
```

**My question: How can I change the value of 'i' (on *MyFunction*) using the *changeValue* function?**

Also: I badly need read some guides about this, could someone give me a link to a good one?

Comment: *"Understanding Local Scope"* Local scope is defined with the declaration of a function. A variable is defined in a local scope when inside a function you declare the variable using a `var` statement. Nothing outside that function will have access to that variable.

Comment: People seem to like [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/). [Chapter 2](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter2.html) has the basics on variables, then [Chapter 3](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html) gets into variable scope in functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `changeValue()` to be in the same scope as `i`:

```
function myFunction(){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){     
        alert(i);     
        changeValue();     
        alert(i);     
    }
    function changeValue() { i = 99; }
}
```

Or, put `i` in the same scope as `changeValue()`:

```
var i;
function changeValue() { i = 99; }
function myFunction(){   
    // var i; // don't define i here
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){     
        alert(i);     
        changeValue();     
        alert(i);     
    }     
}
```

Alternatively, you can tell `changeValue()` what the value of `i` is, then have it return the new value:

```
function changeValue(i) {
    return i + 1;
}
```

Then:

```
i = changeValue(i);
```

**Edit:** To illustrate scope:

```
var a = 0;  //  global scope - accessible everywhere via a
            //  unless overridden by a locally scoped a
            //  always accessible via window.a

function doSomething () {
    var a = 1;  //  local scope - you can still access window.a
    var b = 2;  //  local scope - accessible to child scopes, but not global scope

    function innerFunction () {
        var a = 3;  //  you no longer have access to the parent function's a variable
                    //  you can still access window.a
        var c = 4;  //  only accessible here (since no child scopes exist)

        alert(window.a);  //  0
        alert(a);         //  3
        alert(b);         //  2
        alert(c);         //  4
    }

    innerFunction();

    alert(window.a);  //  0
    alert(a);         //  1
    alert(b);         //  2
    alert(c);         //  undefined - unavailable in this scope
}

doSomething();

alert(window.a);  //  0
alert(a);         //  0
alert(b);         //  undefined - unavailable in this scope
alert(c);         //  undefined - unavailable in this scope
```

Comment: I could define i if I wanted, but I would need to use 'window.i' to access the global right?

Comment: @ogps92 - Only if you also have `i` defined in your local scope as well.  If the only `i` defined (via `var i`) in your scope chain is `window.i`, then simply referencing `i` works just fine.

Comment: I was going to accept the answer of someone else, but your edit was so powerful that It would be wrong to don't accept it

Answer (score 1):

You could simply return the value :

```
function changeValue(i) {
 return i + 2;
}

 for(i=0;i<3;i++){ 
        alert(i); 
        i = changeValue(i); 
        alert(i); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(){
    var i;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        alert(i);
        i = changeValue();
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

while changeValue():

```
changeValue(){
return new_i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using `var` within `myFunction`, it becomes a local variable in that scope. So you can't access it anywhere outside not matter how hard you try.

Use `window.i` instead of `var i` in both places and it should work,

---

You can simply avoid `window.` and use `i` directly without `var` prefix or even place the `var i` declaration outside both the functions... but effectively the variable become a part of the `window` object. (In general all global variable in JS are part of the `window` object)

Comment: that is good to know, I always use different var-names because I thought they would somehow interfere if I used a func inside a func! (but now I understand that only happens with Global vars)

Comment: It's probably a very dangerous idea to attach such a generically named variable like `i` to `window`. That could introduce many more problems than it solves.

Comment: The one answer that really explained how a variable is scoped gets a down vote?

Answer (score 0):

You can only manipulate variables that are inside your scope. Currently, the scope of `i` is confined to `myFunction()`.

[This](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/) is an excellent article to get you started understanding the scope rules in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Both `changeValue` and `myFunction` exist in the global scope. If you define `i` in myFunction, it's only accessible inside `myFunction` and its children, functions defined inside myFunction. The 'scope chain' (I'm just thinking up a word for it) looks like this:

```
myFunction <- window
```

changeValue also exists in the global scope. It is called from myFunction, but that doesn't change the scope in which it exists. Its scope chain is like this:

```
changeValue <- window
```

If you only use changeValue inside myFunction, you can do this:

```
function myFunction() {
  function changeValue() { /* stuff */ }
  /* more stuff */
}
```

changeValue's scope chain is now like this:

```
changeValue <- myFunction <- window
```

As `i` exists in `myFunction`, it now also exists in `changeValue`.